# Changing number of backup from x to y in ignite cluster

Tags: ignite, distributed-cache

I have a ignite cluster running with 8 nodes.

I created one table
**CREATE TABLE Sample(....) WITH "template=partitioned,backups=1"**
and it is having 300 Millon entries (cache: "SampleCache")

Now I want to change back up to **0**. How can I do this?

Documentation of [ALTER](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/alter-table) doesn't specify anything related to this.

I want to avoid dropping table and creating again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no support for changing cache configuration after it is started. This means you will have to drop table and create another one.